# How to calculate gradient and correlation coefficients with moving window in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, accelerometer, feature-selection, pearson-correlation

I am working on pedestrian step detection algorithm (acceleration data), I need to calculate **statistical features** from my filtered signal not raw data. I have already calculated mean, var and std and now I want to calculate correlation **coefficients and gradient** from filtered data. My filter data is of 1x37205 double. I calculated these features using for loop with moving window size=2samples and 50% overlap of previous window. Below I am attaching the code I tried. But when I run this for corrcoef it gives 1's as output for the whole data and for gradient it gives error `Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`. I am unable to understand well. Could some one suggest me or provide any code help in matlab and/or how can I work on that?

```
windowsize=2; 
%%C is used for corrcoef and G for gradient. %%Data_filtered is caclulated 
%%from acceleration xyz.
function [C, G] = features(Data_filtered, window)
C=zeros(length(Data_filtered),1);
G=zeros(length(Data_filtered),1);
for i=window:(length(Data_filtered))
C(i,1)=corrcoef(Data_filtered(i+1-window:i));
end;
for i=window:(length(Data_filtered))
G(i,1)=gradient(Data_filtered(i+1-window:i));
end;
end
```

Comment: The sporadic **bold** text in this question makes it 10x harder to read. Please [edit] your question to remove this visual noise and improve the code you've provided by turning it into a [mcve].

Comment: What did you expect ? `corrcoef(every_1D_vector)` will always output 1, since there is, obviously, a perfect linear correlation between each element of your vector. What is the point of using `corrcoef()` on a 1D vector ?

Comment: sorry for above, alright i need to combine two features for the calculation, but when i do this the result is still same. see below code. M is mean and V is variance.          CC=[M V];
for i=window:(length(CC))
    C(i,1)=corrcoef(CC(i+1-window:i));
end;